City and people AI simulator (modeling, and getting to interact, a society)
I am looking for a software which will allow you to

build a city, similar, to what can be done in 3D AutoCAD

choose avatars, to place, inside, the city (sort of like with the Sims

in edit mode, click on a character, and, program


-- it's health conditions, such as allergies, likes, dislikes, etc
-- things such as, "if a dog comes by, throw at it a vegetable so that the dog can eat it"
I want to be able to program all the characters, not via code, but via AI.
That is, the program allows me to type things about the characters, and understands them.
It knows when people need to exercise or get hungry.
It knows when people need to go to sleep because they get tired (that is, each person, also has physiological properties).
The nice thing, is that you get to code them with words
"In the morning, make yourself a bagel".
"When you enforcer Sally, ask her if she bought those books and ask her if she needs help with her homework."
You can get, complex.
"When you see Katie, figure out whether she's yet, bought, a bird, at the pet shop (by swinging a bird house in front of her)".
You can program all these things, via, chat boxes that look like thought clouds in comics when people speak or think, and write AI stuff in them.
Then, you run the simulation.
You can drag on the timeline, and click on the calendar. This way, you can drag a simulation up to a given time in the future and see what happens, (or you can fast forward and view the whole simulation, as, it moves fast (at increased speed, to, see what happens.
You can go anywhere in the situation by going around in a flying drone (perhaps even one that can fly though walls, or place different views on the screen of things happening at different locations on the same screen.
This, would be, an instructive, figurative
Game
Which would let you figure a society out, how, things about people and things that get placed in their mind, lead them, to do things.
You could use it to program talks and television programs (to cater, to, positive, wanted, societal, effects.
Or to plan (cater to), your, conversations with others (or your actions.
Or, if you were a teacher, you could plan and calibrate your teachings (and, simulate, actions, in the classroom, as well as view and post analyze post classroom post action behaviors.
You could have the game also input some randomness (to test, stuff
It would be nice.
But it would be nice, even, nicer, if you could place each character with their health conditions and thoughts into the setting, program everything, reprogram, and get to the point where you have stimulated, and, constructed, everything in a small (perhaps, autonomous (or not), society
And view it interact, and work (even with respect to boredom, as, you programmed, their modus operandi.
Hello,
I am very immersed in the idea of a society that talks to me via my phone or PC, and, I program it to see how it works or what, people can, or, could do, in various situations (how encounters interact
While most television programs or infections see you immersed in a given character and it can be dangerous because you can stimulate their actions unconsciously, running a "society, simulation,", like this, is healthier (because, you can see, then, even program, via textural AI (for the best), everything, without feeling like you are any character in particolar (user, see, instrospect, understand, and understand everything.
Who is willing to create a group of programmers to implement such useful software for Android and PCs and sell it?
I would be very happy if this happened, the benefits to society would be enormous (and, the benefits, every growing
Thank you for your collaboration.
Thank you for your support.
Thank you for your help.
Thanks.

This is all very highly specific and complex. Are you brainstorming an idea for a new computer game, or are you looking to hire someone to code a full game for you? I doubt someone would just be willing to make this from the ground up just for you. It would likely take a large company with full time teams a lot of time to come up with such infrastructure.
